# Ideal Donut-style Texture Coordinates?

Tags: texturing, texture-coordinates

I'm making an iris texture, and I need to make distort the texture coordinates, I'm looking for a radial texture coordinate system which works with either object, generated, or UV coordinates, that doesn't need some special deformations (no using a deform modifier to make a doughnut)

My current design (please ignore the coordinate noise):[image]